# I am trying to use the gulpfile.js to convert the sass file to css file but it can't work

Tags: sass, gulp, compass-sass, gulp-sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aDQU.png)

it tried typing gulp to build up the js file and compile it to create a new index.css file

Comment: Did you install gulp both locally and globally?

Answer (score 0):

Install gulp globally using command

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Then Install gulp locally inside your project folder:

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

Then run

```
npm gulp
```

The key step is to first install gulp globally.